# How to Upload the files into the SiteAssets Library by SharePoint Hosted App Model

Tags: sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-hosted-app

I want to upload the Jquery and supported files in to the Site Asset library by SharePoint Hosted Apps,

I have create a SharePoint Hosted App, added the files in the Modules

```
 <Module Name="ZoneTabsFiles" Url="SiteAssets">
    <File Path="ZoneTabsFiles\jquery-1.11.2.min.js" Url="jquery-1.11.2.min.js" ReplaceContent="TRUE" />
    <File Path="ZoneTabsFiles\jquery-ui.css" Url="jquery-ui.css" ReplaceContent="TRUE" />
    <File Path="ZoneTabsFiles\jquery-ui.min.js" Url="jquery-ui.min.js" ReplaceContent="TRUE" />
    <File Path="ZoneTabsFiles\ZoneTabs.js" Url="ZoneTabs.js" ReplaceContent="TRUE" />

  </Module>
```

The Apps is successfully getting activated but the files are not visible.

Similarly I want to upload the `.webpart` file to web part catalog.

Comment: Have you tried adding the Type="GhostableInLibrary" attribute to each element file in your module?

Answer (score 2):

You app will provision these files to your App Web and not your Host Web. What you need is to upload your files through JS.

Here is a good write up: 
http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2013/05/sp2013-host-web-apps-provisioning-files.html